# Present Spawning

Tags: wizard101

I have found multiple presents around the Commons in Wizard City. There is an [old post from 2013](http://www.wizard101central.com/forums/showthread.php?379173-Present-Spawn-Point-Maps!-(work-in-progress-feel-free-to-add)), on Wizard101 Central, that has a bunch of different locations. The thread is closed now, and I have already noticed two places not on the map.

**Is there a comprehensive guide on where to find presents?**